# Change the color of a slider's point when click on it

Tags: html, css, materialize

I use [Materialize CSS](http://materializecss.com/) and I have a range - slider in my form. I want to make the bullet changing a color and size when you click on it. But, I cannot make it work. Here is what I try to do:

```
<p class="range-field"><input type="range" id="years" min="17" max="30" /></p>

    input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #277F31;
    border: medium none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 14px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    width: 14px;
    }

    input[type="range"]:active:-moz-range-thumb {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 black;
    border: medium none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 24px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    width: 24px;
    }
```

However, the `active` on CSS doesn't work here. I tried also with focus but still nothing.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you should use the double colon notation for pseudo elements (eg slider thumb), like in your first selector :

```
input[type="range"]:active::-moz-range-thumb
                          ^^
                         two colons here
```

don't forget about the cross browser compatibility

```
::-webkit-slider-thumb /* for webkit based browsers */
::-ms-thumb /* Internet explorer 10+ */
```

Comment: How I missed that...Thank you a lot. I will accept your answer when it will be available :)

Comment: It’s not a CSS2 vs CSS3 thing. In CSS3 `:` is the notation for a pseudoclass, `::` is the notation for a pseudoelement. You’re correct though in that `-moz-range-thumb` is a pseudoelement and should have a `::` though.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a jQuery solution?

```
$('#bullet-id').mousedown(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});
$('#bullet-id').mouseup(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
});
```

If you do this, would be worth making sure you catch the mouse out events to reset back to the original CSS also.